# How can I deploy DLL files created by a Fortran function and call them from Mathematica

Tags: interoperability, .netlink, windows

This is my Fortran function, established by Intel visual Fortran 11.1

```
FUNCTION MYADD(X,Y)
 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::MYADD
 REAL(8) X,Y,MYADD
 MYADD=X+Y
end FUNCTION
```

A corresponding `.dll` file is created,`MDLL.dll` (64bit version) and I put this file in the `$Path` directory.

In a Mathematica notebook, I input:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
fun=DefineDLLFunction["MYADD", "MDLL.dll", "double", {"double", "double"}]
fun[1.0,2.0]
```

But it gives me an error:

```
 NET::netexcptn: A .NET exception occurred: System.DllNotFoundException: 
     unable to load DLL"MDLL.dll": can not find corresponding module 
     (error form HRESULT:0x8007007E).
     in Wolfram.NETLink.DynamicDLLNamespace.DLLWrapper1.MYADD(Double , Double).
```

Comment: It may mean that your dll can't be found. Try adding the directory where you store it, to the PATH environmental variable, and see if that helps. You will have to reboot or at least log off your machine after changing PATH, to see the effect.

Comment: Or even simpler, just specify the full pathname in the second argument.

Comment: @Ajasja This won't work if the dll in question is loaded not directly but from some other dll (which may or may not be the case, I don't know).

Comment: If I remember right, NetLink can call only C DLL's.

Comment: @asim No, a DLL is a DLL, it does not matter which program produced it. The calling convention may need to be specified, but most are cdecl or stdcall anyway.

Comment: I did not mean Mathematica's `$Path` - it has nothing to do with the loading of dll-s. I meant Windows environmental variable `PATH` - I thought I expressed this rather clearly. What you have to do is to add the drectory holding your dll to the PATH, then reboot the computer and test again.

Comment: You can also use `LibraryLink` to do that, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22622/6048) is an example.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Even the path is corrected, it still cannot run, since the argument type should {"double*", "double*"}.
Here is my memo on calling dll created by gfortran using NETLink:

---

Advantages of NETLink as compared to Mathlink:

1. Fortran functions and subroutines can be called using NETLink without writing an additional C wrapper which is necessary in Mathlink.
2. NETLink can access all the functions and subroutines in the fortran code by calling the dll file, not only one.
3. And it seems to me NETLink is faster than Mathlink.

   - Calling a fortran function

Suppose we have a fortran code *testfunction.f90*

```
REAL(8) FUNCTION testfunction(x,y)
  REAL(8), DIMENSION(2) :: x
  REAL(8) :: y
  testfunction = (x(1)+x(2)) * y
END FUNCTION
```

We can compile it and build a dll

```
gfortran -c testfunction.f90
gfortran -shared -mrtd -o testfunction.dll testfunction.o
```

Now the function `testfunction(x,y)` in *testfunction.dll* can be called after loading the .NET/Link package

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
ReinstallNET["Force32Bit" -> True]; (* or InstallNET["Force32Bit"->True] *)

(* set to the directory of the notebook, and the dll file is in the same dir *)
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]; 
path = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "testfunction.dll"}];
TestFunction = DefineDLLFunction["testfunction_", path, "double", {"double[]", "double*"}];
```

`TestFunction[{1.0, 2.0}, 3.0]` gives the correct result `9.0`.

Explanations:

`DefineDLLFunction`: the first argument is the function name to be called. It has changed from `testfunction` to `testfunction_`, and might be `TESTFUNCTION` or other depending on the fortran compiler. `path` is the complete path to the dll file. `"double"` is the return type. The last argument contains the types of the arguments. Note the presence of `[]` for an array and `*` for others. 
If `*` is missing, there will be an error message saying

```
NET::netexcptn: A .NET exception occurred: 
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. 
at Wolfram.NETLink.DynamicDLLNamespace.DLLWrapper...testfunction_(Double[],Double).
```

If `[]` is missing or written as `*` by mistake, the error message is

```
NET::methodargs: Improper arguments supplied for method named testfunction_."
```

Before making revisions to the dll file, one should use `ReinstallNET["Force32Bit" -> True]` to quit and restart the .NET runtime

- Calling a fortran subroutine

see also the post [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/yxS7kD6CmRI)

*testsubroutine.f90*

```
SUBROUTINE testsubroutine(x,y,z)
  REAL(8), DIMENSION(2), INTENT(in) :: x
  REAL(8), INTENT(in) :: y
  REAL(8), DIMENSION(2), INTENT(out) :: z
  z(1) = x(1) * y
  z(2) = x(2) * y
  RETURN
END SUBROUTINE
```

*testsubroutine.dll* can be built as before. In Mathematica, after loading NETLink and `ReinstallNET["Force32Bit" -> True]`,

```
path2 = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "testsubroutine.dll"}]
TestSubroutine = DefineDLLFunction["testsubroutine_", path2, "void", 
{"Double[]", "Double*", "Double[]"}]
```

Now we should create a .NET object, which is to be sent to `testsubroutine_` at the place of `z` to store the results

```
(* Any real or integer numbers can be put in the list. 
"System.Double[]" is necessary if any of the numbers is an integer. *)  
res = MakeNETObject[{0, 0.}, "System.Double[]"]
```

Now let's test a case:

```
TestSubroutine[{1., 2.}, 3., res] (* res receives the calculated results *)

(* translate the .NET object results into a Mathematica expression  *)
NETObjectToExpression[res]
```

The results are the desired {3., 6.}.

Comment: What a wonderful answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: Good answer! BTW (probably you have known this), in practice, we can also put different functions and subroutines together in the same .dll file.

Comment: You are definitely right. You can put whatever number of functions in the same dll.

Comment: @unstable Do you know a way to find the name of the function in the dll (i.e. the first argument of `DefineDLLFunction`)? I'm trying to use a F# dll in the same way, and I keep getting the error `NET::netexcptn: "A .NET exception occurred: "System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point [...]"`

Comment: VERY usefull answer! many thanks for putting a complete and detailed one!

Comment: When using a 64 bit gfortran `ReinstallNET["Force32Bit" -> True]` is not needed.

Comment: And under Windows and `$VersionNumber >= 12.2` one has to, unfortunately, do first `SetOptions[ValueQ, Method -> "Legacy"]`

Comment: @sebhofer Sorry for the late answer for I haven't checked this for a long time... You can use an external tool "DLL export viewer" to see all the functions in a given dll file.

Answer (score 1):

Using Mono 6.12.0.122 this works in Linux, with Mathematica 13.0.1 :

```
SetEnvironment["LD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Libraries", $SystemID}]];
    SetEnvironment["DISPLAY" -> ":0"];
    Needs["NETLink`"];
    NETLink`InstallNET[];
    path2 = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "testsubroutine.dll"}];
    TestSubroutine = DefineDLLFunction["testsubroutine_", path2,  "void", {"Double[]", "Double*", "Double[]"}];
    res = MakeNETObject[{0, 0.}, "System.Double[]"];
    TestSubroutine[{1.0, 2.0}, 3.0, res];
    NETObjectToExpression[res]
```