# How can I link the c library GAUL into Mathematica?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, librarylink

Is there a way to load the library [GAUL (Genetic Algorithm Utility Library)](http://gaul.sourceforge.net) for use within Mathematica?

Comment: Probably. Likely not simple, though. Have you looked at [MathLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MathLinkAPI.html) or [LibraryLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/LibraryLink.html)? ... Obviously you have (from the tags), if only briefly. So, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm reading the documentation on LibraryLink now, but it's is a bit cryptic...

Comment: [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/linking-fortran-with-librarylink/22622#22622) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22679/how-to-convert-data-types-in-a-librarylink-wrapper/22797#22797) are examples about using LibraryLink to load external libraries. Maybe it's helpful.