# Why LibraryLink function crashes at a second time?

Tags: bugs, kernel, librarylink, crash

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.3**

---

**Update**

As [Todd Gayley](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4783/todd-gayley) commented under [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan)'s answer, this is a bug.

---

I'm trying link one of Lapack's function to Mathematica through LibraryLink, and the Library function works great at the first execution but crashes at the second time.

Here is the code (modified from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22622/1364))

```
MMASrc="
#include <WolframLibrary.h>
#include <WolframCompileLibrary.h>

DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion(){
  return WolframLibraryVersion;
}
DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData){
  return 0;
}

EXTERN_C void zspsv_(char* UPLO, const mint* N, mint* NRHS, mcomplex* A, mint* IPIV, mcomplex* B, mint* LDB, mint* INFO);


EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int lpkSolveAXBS(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){

  MTensor ta=MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
  MTensor tb=MArgument_getMTensor(Args[1]);
  mint N=*MTensor_getDimensionsMacro(tb);
  mcomplex* A=MTensor_getComplexDataMacro(ta);
  mcomplex* B=MTensor_getComplexDataMacro(tb);

  char U='U';
  mint IPIV[N];
  mint NRHS=1;
  mint LDA=N,LDB=N;
  mint INFO;
  mint i,j;

  mcomplex AP[N*(N+1)/2];

  for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    for(i=0;i<=j;i++)
      AP[i + (j+1)*j/2] = A[i*N+j];

  zspsv_(&U,&N,&NRHS,AP,IPIV,B,&LDB,&INFO);

  MArgument_setMTensor(Res,tb);
  return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}


";
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];

CreateLibrary[MMASrc,"lpk","Debug"->True,"TargetDirectory"->"/tmp",
        "CompileOptions"->"-llapack"];

A={{1. +0. I,0. +0. I,0. -6.94908*^-13 I,0. -6.94908*^-13 I},
           {0. +0. I,1. +0.0352595 I,0. -4.51893*^-11 I,0. -4.51893*^-11 I},
           {0. -6.94908*^-13 I,0. -4.51893*^-11 I,1. +0.0376938 I,0. +0. I},
           {0. -6.94908*^-13 I,0. -4.51893*^-11 I,0. +0. I,1. +0.0378932 I}};

B={1. +0. I,0. +0. I,0. +6.94908*^-13 I,0. +6.94908*^-13 I};

lpkSolve=LibraryFunctionLoad["/tmp/lpk.dylib","lpkSolveAXBS",
        {{Complex,2},{Complex,1}},{Complex,1}]
(*LibraryFunction[<>,lpkSolveAXBS,{{Complex,2},{Complex,1}},{Complex,1}]*)

Abs[LinearSolve[A,B]-lpkSolve[A,B]]//Max
(*2.02047*10^-28*)

Table[LinearSolve[A,B],{40000}];//AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.470767,Null}*)

Table[lpkSolve[A,B],{40000}];//AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.086038,Null}*)

Table[lpkSolve[A,B],{40000}];//AbsoluteTiming
```

In executing `In[10]`, I hear a beep sound and then the kernel crashes and there is no output. Why the kernel crashes at the second time of invoking the LibraryLink function? How to fix that?

Comment: The link to the source of the code is missing.

Comment: @b.gatessucks thanks for point it out, I meant to use `lpkSolve` instead of `LinearSolve` in `In[10]`, but I see both cause the kernel to crash. I'll correct it so that it wouldn't cause confusion.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I've corrected that. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @xslittlegrass, I don't know the answer to your question, but would you be interested in a top level interface to BLAS and/or LAPACK? Concerning the crash, I'd send that to the technical support.

Comment: You should not forget that the memory order for C and Fortran arrays is different. This will not be apparent for the matrix inverse example because of the double transposition and the fact that `Transpose@Inverse@Transpose[M] === Inverse[M]`, but will be important in other cases and could easily lead to crashes if not properly observed (especially for non-square matrices). By the way, you may be interested to learn that `LinearAlgebra\`LAPACK\`GESV` and `LinearAlgebra\`LAPACK\`POSV` exist. Unfortunately there's no `SPSV`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks for mentioning it. Actually in another non-symetric problem I was confused by the results for quiet a while before I realized the different memory ordering. I'm very interested to learn that `LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`GESV` and `LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`POSV` exist, I never knew them before. Could you give some reference to how to use them? I tried to google them but find nothing interesting. Thanks very much.

Comment: @xslittlegrass For the sake of future visitors, could you reconsider taking any of the current answers as *accepted answer*? I explained [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10651297#10651297) that what you experience is clearly a bug and cloning the tensor is not a solution neither is the documentation wrong. I talked to Todd Gayley, one of the persons in charge of LibraryLink at Wolfram. Please look at his comment under my answer.

Comment: @halirutan Thanks very much for bringing this question to Todd Gayley. I've unaccepted the wrong answer and updated the question to refer to Todd Gayley's comment under your answer. Thanks very much for letting me know.

Comment: @rubenko: Yes, a top level interface would be great as the built in Mathematica functions for linearsolve and inverse are not compilable

Comment: @ruebenko Yes, I'm also very interested in a top level interface to BLAS and LAPACK.

Comment: @asim, send me an email at ruebenko TAT wolfram.com and I can send you the notebooks.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm still seeing this problem in 10.3.1 on OS X 10.11.4. I see you edited the header, what system are you using?

Answer (score 7):

An observation, rather than an answer to the *why* question.

The question suggests, that the problem might have something to do with the used lapack library. As it turns out, at least on my machine it doesn't. We can replace the C-code with the most simple routine which is taking an input tensor and returning exactly the same tensor as result.

```
MTensor ta = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
MArgument_setMTensor(Res,ta);
return LIBRARY_NO _ERROR;
```

Now, the underlying problem seems to be the very small numbers which were used as input. We can pin it down to `0. + 6.94908*^-13 I` which seems to be the cause. Unfortunately, there is another important ingredient to crash the kernel: it's the usage of `Table`. When I try the same with `Do` or `ConstantArray` it works. `Array` crashed my *Mathematica* completely. Therefore, to make it more fun for you too, please ensure that you really have some unsaved notebooks open, when you try this.

So while this crashes the kernel

```
Table[testFunc[{0. - 6.94908*^-13 I}], {40000}];
Table[testFunc[{0. - 6.94908*^-13 I}], {40000}];
```

this does not, even if I evaluate it several times

```
Do[testFunc[{0. - 6.94908*^-13 I}], {40000}];
Do[testFunc[{0. - 6.94908*^-13 I}], {40000}];
```

the same is true for `ConstantArray`.

### Test Code

```
MMASrc =     
  "# include <WolframLibrary.h>
   # include <WolframCompileLibrary.h>

   DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion(){
     return WolframLibraryVersion;
   }

   DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData){
     return 0;
   }

   EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int test(
     WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){

     MTensor ta=MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
     MArgument_setMTensor(Res,ta);
     return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
   }";

Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
lib = CreateLibrary[MMASrc, "test", "Debug" -> True, "TargetDirectory" -> "/tmp"];
testFunc = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "test", {{Complex, 1}}, {Complex, 1}];
```

Comment: I feel your pain, but did you really have unsaved notebooks open when testing this?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Fortunately, only the notebook with the toy-code above. Therefore, I only had to edit the OP's code again to get the reduced example.

Comment: In principle, you don't need to use `FileNames` to get the full path of the libs as `"SystemIncludeDirectories" -> Automatic` should handle that.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, thanks. I simplified the post.

Comment: The crash in this sample code is clearly a bug. It should work with the default Automatic passing. And it cannot be made to work no matter what tensor-passing convention you specify. I've reported the bug, and if I get any further details I will report back.

Comment: The edit to the original post states "fixed in 10.3" but this is still present in 12.1.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related to 'small numbers' - it still crashes when 10^-13 -> 10^-3 (and all other values too...). It *does* seem to have something to do with `Table` - `Do` does not cause the crash. Also, I find the same behaviour with simple LibraryLink functions combined with `Map`.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the memory management write up for tensor. I suspect you are returning a pointer to an automatic tensor that is being cleaned up.

[LibrayLink Interaction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html)

> Can you elaborate more on your thoughts, because I read the documentation exactly the opposite way: "For automatic passing, the MTensor is owned by the library function only when that call to the library is active. The function can return the MTensor whether it has been modified or not, but whatever happens, the MTensor cannot be used after the function has returned

Yes. I believe the docs are in error. If you clone an input tensor, or create a new one, and return it the kernel will not crash.

It is my belief that on automatic copy **in** a temporary pointer is created. On an automatic **return** a copy is not made but returned directly. So if you return an input tensor you are returning a tensor pointing to memory that is going to be destroyed. A crash is inevitable.

This works just fine ...

```
    MMASrc = 
"#include <WolframLibrary.h>
#include <WolframCompileLibrary.h>

DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion(){
     return WolframLibraryVersion;
}

DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData){
     return 0;
}
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int test(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){

MTensor T0;
T0=0;
MTensor ta=MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
libData->MTensor_clone( ta, &T0);

MArgument_setMTensor(Res,T0);
     return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}";

Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
lib=CreateLibrary[MMASrc,"test","Debug"->True, "TargetDirectory"->"/tmp"];
testFunc=LibraryFunctionLoad[lib,"test",{{Complex,1}},{Complex,1}];
Table[testFunc[{0.-6.94908^-13I}],{40000}];
Table[testFunc[{0.-6.94908^-13I}],{40000}];
Table[testFunc[{0.-6.94908^-13I}],{40000}];
Table[testFunc[{0.-6.94908^-13I}],{40000}];
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your thoughts, because I read the documentation exactly the opposite way: "For automatic passing, the MTensor is owned by the library function only when that call to the library is active. The function can return the MTensor whether it has been modified or not, but whatever happens, the MTensor cannot be used after the function has returned."

Comment: See my added comments above.

Comment: OK, +1 for trying this out. So this suggests, that there are two copies needed, because *automatic passing* already creates a copy of input tensors and then you have to clone it again? And why does this happens with `Table` and the small numbers only?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works! You mentioned "automatic copy in a temporary pointer is created", what do you mean the temporary pointer, what's its relation to the tensor ta created in the library function? If it is due to the clean process, why it still crash when we use manual pass as `testFunc=LibraryFunctionLoad[lib,"test",{{Complex,1,"Manual"}},{Complex,1}];`? Since in the manual pass, it will "pass in a copy of the MTensor and do not automatically clean".

Comment: And in order to save the time and memory for large matrixes, is it possible to use the disown features or shared passing etc instead of using the cloning process?

Comment: And it seems there is a memory leaking if we use the clone method you showed. If you set the `$HistoryLength` to 0 and repeatedly run `Table[testFunc[{0.-6.94908^-13I}],{40000}];` you can see the memory use of the kernel goes up about 4M each time and never decrease, which is about the same size of memory needed to store `40000` copies of `{0.-6.94908^-13I}`. If we define a `Mathematica` function `f[t_]:=t and run `Table[f[{0.-6.94908^-13I}],{40000}];` we can not see the memory use increase.