# Run a code in Fortran, C++, or Python in Wolfram Mathematica 12 on Mac OS

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, python, c++, fortran

I would like to run an external code, written in Fortran, C++, or Python, within Wolfram Mathematica 12 on my MAC OS. I looked up on Internet and I tried to read the WSTP documentation on Wolfram Mathematica, but I still was not able to solve my issue. Could you please provide me some examples explained step by step in order that I can understand the strategy and I can then implement to there external codes?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Python is going to be the easiest by far through `ExternalEvaluate`. C++ and Fortran will be easiest to do with `LibraryLink` unless you need to call into Mathematica from either of them.

Comment: Read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8438/9490) and then try to ask a more focused question.  This is far too broad I think.

Comment: This is a bit too broad. Please focus the question to a single language, and check these C++ (read this _before_ you attempt Fortran) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8438/12 Fortran: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38018/12 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5706/12 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5675/12 Python: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html

Answer (score 0):

You must first configure MMA to use Python. Here is how to proceed, from the help (version 12.1):

workflow/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate

If you have done the setup, you can execute Python code inside a Notebook. You may e.g. type ">" (Greater) at the beginning of a line. This gives you a Python code cell, where you can type and execute Python code. E.g.:

[image]

Or you may create a Python session, using `ExternalEvaluate` as described in the help:

ref/ExternalValue