# possibility of using `f2py` for interoperability with Fortran

Tags: interoperability, python, fortran

Although interoperability with Fortran could be realised by using `LibraryLink` (e.g., [Linking FORTRAN with Librarylink](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5706/260)), the approach is not so straight forward, in particular for those not familiar with C (such as me).

In comparison with `LibraryLink`, the `numpy` tool [`f2py`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/index.html) provides a much easier way to generate Python modules from Fortran code given the users have basic knowledge of Fortran. In fact, the intermediate step of `f2py` also involves C code, which is similar as the `LibraryLink` approach.

As such, I'm wondering if it's possible for Mathematica to directly use `f2py`-generated files to create Mathematica functions?

Comment: The answer to this question is very likely: No. You should have a look at [LTemplate](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/575100). This requires only rather basic C++ knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, @HenrikSchumacher ! The link is very helpful.