# MathLink linking error after OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) upgrade

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, mac-os-x

After macosx 10.9 mavericks upgrade i have a compilation problem, you can see below. Even the examples given in /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/MacOSX-x86-64/MathLinkExamples are not compiling anymore. It throws an error about the architecture. I also followed the solution given by [MathLink compile errors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6506/mathlink-compile-errors), reinstalling the Xcode and command line tools. It didnt work.

I also checked the *libMLi3.a* for architecture and seems like it is ok

*libMLi3.a: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures libMLi3.a (for architecture i386): current ar archive random library libMLi3.a (for architecture x86_64): current ar archive random library*

and clang/gcc as well

> Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn) Target:
>   x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0 Thread model: posix
>
> gcc -v Configured with:
>   --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn) Target:
>   x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0 Thread model: posix

which are the latest.

**I wonder if anyone manages to compile the MathLink examples after the 10.9 upgrade?**

Here is the error message:

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/MacOSX-x86-64/MathLinkExamples]:>
 g++  -I/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/MacOSX-x86-64/MathLinkExamples/../CompilerAdditions \
addtwotm.o addtwo.o -L/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/MacOSX-x86-64/MathLinkExamples/../CompilerAdditions \
-lMLi3 -lstdc++ -framework Foundation -o addtwo
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::string::find_last_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MLThreads::DestroyName(std::string&) in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
  "std::string::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MLThreads::NameValidQ(std::string&) in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::DestroyName(std::string&) in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
  "std::string::find(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      _mlipinterfacecontainer_get_domain_names in libMLi3.a(mlipinterface.c.o)
      MLNetwork::MLIPAddress::LoadDomainName(bool) in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLIPAddress::IPV4NameQ(std::string) in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLIPAddress::IPV6NameQ(std::string) in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLIPAddress::AutoconfiguredQ() const in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      _pipe_make in libMLi3.a(_pipe.c.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::OldConnectServer() in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
      ...
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Just a quick comment that both MathLink and LibraryLink compilation works fine for me on 10.9 with XCode 5.0.1's command line tools.  Haven't had time to look at your details yet.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you mention, but you did not provide *complete* compilation steps.  Please edit the question and describe *precisely* how you tried to compile the examples, *making sure to include every step*.  You only showed us the linking step and while you mention the version of your clang installation, you used gcc to compile.  Please include the version of the compiler you are actually using.

Comment: Well actually there are no many steps. Just go to the folder  /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/MacOSX-x86-64/MathLinkExamples there you will see MathLink folder, some prebuilt examples and MathLinkExamples folder. In that folder makefile file is already provided and you just need to type "make" to compile all. It is so easy. When you do that it complains. Therefore I have couple of other MathLink programs i wrote compiled long ago seems like they are working in Mathematica, though still couldn't compile.

Comment: Therefore surely you need to have Xcode/Command Line Tools preinstalled to compile the code.

Comment: I added the gcc version info under the question. Carefully looking at my question i think gcc works fine and compiles but clang couldn't link the MathLink objects (i guess in libMLi3.a library) and complains about the architecture.

Comment: I couldn't at first reproduce the problem you described.  This means that we were doing something differently.  This is why even if the compilation steps seem trivial to you, it is very important that you describe them precisely.  Otherwise people here can only try to guess at what you were doing differently from them.  I can see the problem with the supplied makefile but it didn't come up in my own MathLink projects for some reason.

Comment: That difference seems to be that my build procedures include `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6`, which ensures compatibility with 10.6 and later instead of 10.9 only.  If this is used, it automatically links with the libstdc++ compatible with the MathLink library.

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh, I haven't seen this comment of yours. I included this information in my answer since it was a direct result when comparing what `CreateExecutable` does.

Comment: Just a note that, in 10.4 (coming probably in a month or so), the default MacOS MathLink library will be switched to use libc++ by default.  The framework will continue to host the older, libstdc++ version of MathLink using Apple's standard framework versioning scheme.

Answer (score 8):

Basically, I came to the same conclusions as user6629 and Szabolcs. This means there are two solutions for the commandline.

1. Specify `-lstdc++.6` which is very weird, because on my machine `libstdc++.dylib` is just a link to `libstdc++.6.dylib` too. I traced the linker output and it really uses the correct library from `/usr/lib` which gives me some headache.
2. Use `-stdlib=libstdc++ -lstdc++` as suggested by Szabolcs.

There is another solution: Use `CreateExecutable` from the `` <<CCompilerDriver` `` package. Here the `addtwo` example (please set the `TargetDirectory` as you like)

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
src = FileNames["addtwo.*", {FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", 
     "Links", "MathLink"}]}, Infinity]
CreateExecutable[src, "out", "ShellOutputFunction" :> Print, 
 "ShellCommandFunction" :> Print, "TargetDirectory" -> "tmp"]
```

Looking at the compiler command reveals something even more weird

```
/usr/bin/gcc ... -l"MLi3" -lm -lpthread -lstdc++
```

*Mathematica* is using the exact same command which brings up the error in the terminal. 
This reveals that another solution is possible: Specify `-mmacosx-version-min=10.4` which seems to turn on compatibility mode.

Comment: Or really `-mmacosx-version-min` = anything lower than 10.9.  Is 10.4 available in a 64 bit version as well?

Comment: @Szabolcs It seems so. 10.4 is what is used by `CreateExecutable` on my machine.

Comment: I came across the same problem for `CreateExecutable` from `CCompilerDriver` package. I know how to solve this problem in the `Makefile`, but how to solve this problem if I want to use `CreateExecutable`? How to add something like `-stdlib=libstdc++ -lstdc++` in it?

Comment: Try the giving the option `"CompileOptions" -> "-stdlib=libstdc++ -lstdc++"` to `CreateExecutable`. You can find all options in [the documentation under Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCompilerDriver/ref/CreateExecutable.html)

Comment: @halirutan Thanks for your suggestions. My problem has been solved. But a new problem arises. I can create a binary and install in *Mma*. But it never works. I started a new SE [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64751/generating-mathlink-executables-by-ccompilerdriver). It will be great to have your suggestions on that issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've been able to gather:

There are two implementations of the standard C++ library available on OS X: `libstdc++` and [`libc++`](http://libcxx.llvm.org/).  They are not binary compatible and `libMLi3` requires `libstdc++`.

On 10.8 and earlier `libstdc++` is chosen by default, on 10.9 `libc++` is chosen by default.  To ensure compatibility with `libMLi3`, we need to choose `libstdc++` manually.

To do this, add `-stdlib=libstdc++` to the linking command.

---

Note: the Makefile supplied with the MathLink examples uses the `c++` command for linking (not `cc` or `ld`).  In this case the `-lstdc++` option can be removed from the linking command.  However if you use `cc` for linking, then it's necessary to specify both of `-stdlib=libstdc++ -lstdc++`.

Comment: Are you sure this works for you on 10.9? Here, it is crucial that I explicitly specify `-lstdc++` too.

Comment: @halirutan It was working for me because I was linking with `c++` instead of `cc` because I modified the original example makefile.  I updated the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution: libMLi3 wasn't the problem but the standard libstdc++. If you change the *-lstdc++* to *-lstdc++.6* in makefile given in MathLinkExamples folder it compiles w/o problem. I also checked my /usr/lib folder and seems like the link file is present (/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib -> libstdc++.6.dylib) and points the correct library but linker got complains some how.