# Generating Mathlink executables by CCompilerDriver

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, ccompilerdriver

I'm trying to generate a `MathLink` executable by `CCompilerDriver` package. The `MathLink` executable produced by `Makefile` works properly. However, when I'm trying to generate the same thing by `CCompilerDriver`, an executable can be generated and installed without any warnings. But it keeps crashing whenever I tried to use its functions. And the link closed automatically.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Files `cddmathlink.c`, `cddmathlink.tm`, `cddmlio.c`, `cddmlio.h`, `mathlink.h` and the original `Makefile` can be found in
https://github.com/mcmtroffaes/cddlib/tree/master/src-mathlink2 .

One may also find the latest source file for *cddlib* through the link above.

I'm using OS X and I installed `cddlib` and `GMP` libraries via *Homebrew*. So I changed the `Makefile` according to my system and the installation of *Mathematica*, *cddlib* and *GMP*. The `Makefile` works and the resulting executable works properly too. But I don't know how to produce the executable via `CCompilerDriver` package.

**The `Makefile`**

```
MLINKDIR = /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit
SYS = MacOSX-x86-64
CADDSDIR = ${MLINKDIR}/${SYS}/CompilerAdditions
INCDIR = ${CADDSDIR}    
LIBDIR = ${CADDSDIR}
MPREP = ${CADDSDIR}/mprep
RM = rm
EXTRA_LIBS = -stdlib=libstdc++ -lstdc++ -framework Foundation
MATHLINK_LIB = -lMLi4
CC = /usr/bin/clang

BINARIES = cddmlgmp

all : $(BINARIES)

cddmlgmp : cddmathlinktm.o cddmathlink.o cddmlio.o
    ${CC} -I${INCDIR} cddmlio.o cddmathlinktm.o cddmathlink.o -L${LIBDIR} ${MATHLINK_LIB} ${EXTRA_LIBS} -lgmp /usr/local/lib/libcddgmp.a -o cddmlgmp

cddmathlinktm.o: cddmathlinktm.c
    $(CC) -c cddmathlinktm.c

cddmathlink.o: cddmathlink.c
    $(CC) -c cddmathlink.c -o cddmathlink.o

cddmlio.o: cddmlio.c
    $(CC) -DGMPRATIONAL -c cddmlio.c -o cddmlio.o

cddmathlinktm.c : cddmathlink.tm
    ${MPREP} $? > $@

clean:
    ${RM} -rf *.o *tm.c $(BINARIES)
```

**First attempt (not working):**

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
dir = FileNameJoin[{"~/", "OneDrive", "Documents", "Bitbucket", "cddlib", "src-mathlink"}];
src = FileNames[{"cddmathlink.*", "cddmlio.c"}, dir, Infinity];
CreateExecutable[src, "cddmlgmp", "Libraries" -> {"/usr/local/lib/libgmp.a", "/usr/local/lib/libcddgmp.a"}, "Defines" -> "GMPRATIONAL", "ShellOutputFunction" :> Print, "ShellCommandFunction" :> Print, "TargetDirectory" -> dir]
```

**Another attempt (not working either):**

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
dir = FileNameJoin[{"~/", "OneDrive", "Documents", "Bitbucket", "cddlib", "src-mathlink"}];
src = FileNames["cddmathlink.*", dir, Infinity];
srcext = FileNames["cddmlio.c",dir,Infinity];
obj = CreateObjectFile[srcext, "cddmlio", "Defines" -> "GMPRATIONAL", "ShellOutputFunction" :> Print, "ShellCommandFunction" :> Print, "TargetDirectory" -> dir];
CreateExecutable[src, "cddmlgmp", "Libraries" -> {"/usr/local/lib/libcddgmp.a", "/usr/local/lib/libgmp.a"}, "ExtraObjectFiles" -> obj, "ShellOutputFunction" :> Print, "ShellCommandFunction" :> Print, "TargetDirectory" -> dir]
```

Comment: Please post the code or a substitute that demonstrates the problem. Otherwise, it is very hard to say what might be going on here.

Comment: @Oleksandr R.: May I ask what else are needed? Are those  `*.c`, `*.tm` and `*io.c` files useful here? Or you mean the compilation output?

Comment: Well, without the ability to generate or examine the executable, it is really not possible to guess what is wrong with it based on your description. It sounds like the executable is crashing, but who knows what the reason for that may be given what you say here. I personally cannot help you anyway as I don't have a Mac, but the question should contain sufficient information for someone else to be able to reproduce the problem. Otherwise you are depending on someone else having encountered this specific problem before in their own work to know how to answer you.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Thank you so much for your suggestions. I will edit my question to make it reproducible for someone who is interested.