# Possible bug with UpTo

Tags: bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.3 and fixed in 10.4**

--

Just checking whether anyone else can replicate this, or if it's a problem on my computer. The following refuses to execute on my machine, 10.3.1:

```
Take[{{1}}, All, {UpTo@3}]
```

It results in `General::nomem` and `Throw::sysexc`.

The behaviour seems to be for `UpTo`[anything bigger than 3], but not for 2.

The intended behaviour would be for it to output `{{}}`, analogously with

```
Take[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1}, {1, 2, 3}}, All, {UpTo@2}]
```

which outputs `{{2}, {2}, {}, {2}}`.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect.  The last list demands an integer value and `UpTo[3]` does not have such a form.  What are you trying to accomplish?  This works:  `Take[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, All, {UpTo[3]}]`.

Comment: I'm using the fact that `Take[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1}, {1, 2, 3}}, All, {UpTo@2}]` outputs `{{2}, {2}, {}, {2}}`, for instance. I could just use `Take[{{1}}, All, UpTo@3]` and trim down the lists as necessary, but this way was working for when I constructed my prototype using data that let me have 2 instead of 3.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Do you get the out-of-memory on my example? Since it works when {1} is Range[5], I'm very surprised it "runs out of memory" if you make the input *smaller*.

Comment: It's by analogy with `Take[{1,2,3}, {n}]` returning the `n`th element of `Take[{1,2,3}, n]`; hence `Take[{1,2,3}, {UpTo@n}]` should return the `n`th element of `Take[{1,2,3}, UpTo@n]`, or something standard if the list isn't long enough. Experimenting, when n=2 the "something standard" turns out to be `{}`.

Comment: This is a bug which has already been fixed in the development version (this example returns unevaluated with an error message).

Comment: @ilian That's not the direction I'd have liked it fixed in :P but thanks! Given that the behaviour I wanted was not documented, it's perfectly reasonable not to have implemented it.

Comment: @PatrickStevens `{UpTo[n]}` effectively means `{UpTo[n], UpTo[n]}` and in a sequence specification `{m1, m2}` only the second position allows `UpTo`. It would be confusing in the first position.

Comment: @ilian  I am encountering a similar problem with 10.3 when running `FindRoot` under `ParallelTable`.  When will the development version that you mentioned above be released?  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey 10.4 should be coming soon ([source](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34692/mathlink-linking-error-after-os-x-10-9-mavericks-upgrade#comment284931_34692)) but you may be seeing a different problem (this one was specific to `UpTo`). Please consider sending the example to support@wolfram.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer, this bug has been fixed as of Mathematica [10.4.0](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn104.html).

```
Take[{{1}}, All, {UpTo@3}]

During evaluation of Take::seqs: Sequence specification (+n, -n, {+n}, {-n}, {m, n}, 
or {m, n, s}) expected at position 3 in Take[{{1}},All,{UpTo[3]}]. >>

(* Take[{{1}}, All, {UpTo[3]}] *)
```

Answer (score 4):

I indeed got the out-of-memory error in your original example.

This works:

```
Take[{{1}}, All, UpTo@3]
```

I think putting the last argument in braces makes *Mathematica* assume that its contents is an integer, but `UpTo[3]` is not an integer.

Comment: To make the output exactly what I wanted: `If[Length[#] >= 3, Take[#, {3}], {}] & /@ 
 Take[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1}, {1, 2, 3}}, All, UpTo@3]` doesn't have the error.