# Write C/C++ programs calling Mathematica functions

Tags: functions, mathlink-or-wstp, interoperability

I need to write a C/C++ program and call some functions in *Mathematica* especially those like `Solve` or `NDSolve`. The problem is that in the *Mathematica* documentation it seems to me there is no mention about this.

There are plenty of details regarding how to create a C function and then call it from within *Mathematica*, but in my case I need the opposite.

Maybe I did not read well, but can you explain me how to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have a look at this;

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MathLinkCLanguageFunctions.html

I haven't used it in C/C++ but it works fine in C# and Java. Basically you create a connection to a Mathematica kernel and then pass it native data types. Works nicely.

Here is some sample code in Java that I used when I first did this;

```java
import com.wolfram.jlink.*;

public class SampleProgram {

public static void main(String[] argv) {

    KernelLink ml = null;

    try {
        ml = MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink(argv);
    } catch (MathLinkException e) {
        System.out.println("Fatal error opening link: " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    try {
        // Get rid of the initial InputNamePacket the kernel will send
        // when it is launched.
        ml.discardAnswer();

        ml.evaluate("<<MyPackage.m");
        ml.discardAnswer();

        ml.evaluate("2+2");
        ml.waitForAnswer();

        int result = ml.getInteger();
        System.out.println("2 + 2 = " + result);

        // Here's how to send the same input, but not as a string:
        ml.putFunction("EvaluatePacket", 1);
        ml.putFunction("Plus", 2);
        ml.put(3);
        ml.put(3);
        ml.endPacket();
        ml.waitForAnswer();
        result = ml.getInteger();
        System.out.println("3 + 3 = " + result);

        // If you want the result back as a string, use evaluateToInputForm
        // or evaluateToOutputForm. The second arg for either is the
        // requested page width for formatting the string. Pass 0 for
        // PageWidth->Infinity. These methods get the result in one
        // step--no need to call waitForAnswer.
        String strResult = ml.evaluateToOutputForm("4+4", 0);
        System.out.println("4 + 4 = " + strResult);

    } catch (MathLinkException e) {
        System.out.println("MathLinkException occurred: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        ml.close();
    }
}
}
```

The connection string argv should look something like this

```
String argv = "-linkmode launch -linkname 'C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\8.0\\mathkernel.exe'";
```

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/JLink/tutorial/WritingJavaProgramsThatUseMathematica.html

Comment: Could you provide a simple Java(or C#) program that calls Mathematica to solve an equation? I know that creating these type of examples do [take time](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5675/877) but in the long run maybe others could benefit from your experience.

Comment: Not a problem jmlopez. The standard Wolfram example is a good one I think.

Comment: @Cam: You used the method 'evaluate' in order to tell Mathematica to load a script of yours! Great, what is the equivalent in C? Do you now? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Andry I don't have any first hand experience with C/Mathematica links but it looks like you call it more like the putFunction method call in the Java. Have a look at this; http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingExpressionsInExternalPrograms.html

Comment: I regret that I have to downvote this. The question asks about C/C++, but the solution is in Java! The link provided goes to the top level of MathLink, but the whole point of the question is that MathLink docs generally cover Mathematica -> C rather than the other way around.  (I have a similar problem now, which brought me to this question.)

Comment: The link is clearly C->Mathematica. "The MathLink library provides a collection of C language functions for interacting with Mathematica via MathLink". The Java code was in response to the first comment.

Comment: If you could point me to the specific page that demonstrates the "round trip" in C that you have shown in Java, then I would be happy to eat crow.  What I see on the Mathlink documentation is very high-level.

Answer (score 9):

The other answers ignore that you are asking about C or C++ (not C# or Java!)

Mathematica can be called from C (or C++) through the MathLink interface (recently renamed to WSTP).  To learn it, I recommend reading this old MathLink tutorial by Todd Gayley:

- Original version in PostScript: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/174/
- PDF conversion: http://edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf

Section 2 discusses what you are asking for: calling Mathematica from a C program rather than the reverse case (which is better covered in the official documentation)

You will find several example programs (like `factor.c`) in the directory opened by this command:

```
SystemOpen@
 FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", 
   "MathLink", "DeveloperKit", $SystemID, "MathLinkExamples"}]
```

It is also useful to experiment with setting up MathLink connections in pure Mathematica code. This will help you understand the basic procedure before you try to implement the same in C:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CallingSubsidiaryWolframSystemProcesses.html

Answer (score 7):

### C Style

To Call Mathematica functions from `C/C++` you need to use [`ML_`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/mathlink.h.html) or [`WS_`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WSTPAPI.html) functions. Mathematica is now "replacing" `MathLink` with `WSTP`. However function names are mostly similar. There are C style `WSPutT` functions that are used to send an input of type `T` to mathematica. and the output is fetched from mathematica using [`WSNextPacket`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/c/WSNextPacket.html) and `WSGetT` functions. To use these accessing functions first a link needs to be established [`WSOpenArgcArgv`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/c/WSOpenArgcArgv.html). The [C language Reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/c/WSOpenArgcArgv.html) lists the functions that you will need to communicate with mathematica using 
C/C++

### C++ (with mathematica++)

I was mostly interested to use mathematica from C++. So I developed one C++ library [`mathematica++`](http://neelex.com/mathematica++) that uses template magic for easier interoperability between C++ and Mathematica. The usage example below is copied from the [project page](https://gitlab.com/neel.basu/mathematicapp).

```
symbol x("x");
value  res;
std::string method = "Newton";

shell << Values(FindRoot(ArcTan(1000 * Cos(x)), List(x, 1, 2),  Rule("Method") = method));
shell >> res;
std::vector<double> results = cast<std::vector<double>>(res);
std::cout << results[0] << std::endl; // Prints 10.9956
```

With `mathematica++` you declare a mathematica function using `MATHEMATICA_DECLARE(FunctionName)` and then use the function `FunctionName` in C++. Like in the example above `FindRoot` is being used to solve the equation. It builds an equivalent chain of `WS_` functions on runtime. The template function `cast<T>` can be sued to cast mathematica returned results back to C++ `STL` types.

```
symbol i("i"); // declare mathematica symbol i
value result_list; // declare the variable to hold the result
shell << Table(i, List(i, 1, 10)); // In Mathematica Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]
shell >> result_list;
std::cout << result_list << std::endl; // Prints List[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
std::cout << result_list->stringify() << std::endl; // Prints List[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
std::vector<int> list;
list = cast<std::vector<int>>(result_list);
```

`shell.import("/path/to/package.m")` can be used to import a mathematica package.

```
shell << Import("/path/to/package.m")`
```

also yields the same as well. Because `Import` is also a mathametica function that can be declared using `MATHEMATICA_DECLARE`

I have tested it only on Linux and Mac platforms, but it should work on windows also. The Project is in Free BSD License.

[mathematica++ gitlab repository](https://gitlab.com/neel.basu/mathematicapp) | [website](http://neelex.com/mathematica++) | [wiki](https://gitlab.com/neel.basu/mathematicapp/wikis/home)

Comment: "However function names are mostly similar." They are not mostly similar, they are *exactly the same*.

Comment: Yes. I guessed this. But I didn't find any supporting link that confirms this. So I played safe. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: "Mathematica is now replacing MathLink with WSTP." I know that's what they say, but that's not what they do. LibraryLink still *requires* using the `mathlink.h` header. This is probably because the kernel itself uses the ML functions internally (this is visible when opening the executable with a hex editor), and LibraryLink libraries run in the kernel process.  It's a shame that even the LibraryLink documentation shows WS stuff *which doesn't even work*. It's ridiculous.