# Using .Net link with fortran DLL created by Intel Fortran

Tags: .netlink, fortran

I am following [unstable's wonderful answer on .NET and fortran](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5637/4742).

I can reproduce his result using gfortran without problem. But I want to use Intel Fortran, because gfortran generates slower code on my computer.

All the other steps are the same, only the dll is generated by the following command

```
ifort /dll testfunction.f90
```

After I install .NET and load the dll, running `TestFunction[{1.0, 2.0}, 3.0]` gives me errors.

> NET::netexcptn: A .NET exception occurred:
>   System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 无法在
>   DLL"D:\w\WORK\mathematica\NET\testfunction.dll"中找到名为"testfunction_"的入口点。
>   在
>   Wolfram.NETLink.DynamicDLLNamespace.DLLWrapper1.testfunction_(Double[]
>   , Double& ).

The Chinese part seems to say that it can't find the entrance point named "testfunction_"

How can I solve this?

Comment: Different Fortran compilers follow different name mangling specifications. This is most likely the problem you face here.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Hi,OleksandrR. I know intel fortran will uppercase all the subroutine name. But change the name also didn't work. How to solve this?