# Integrate fortran function into Mathematica

Tags: windows, .netlink, fortran

I was trying to use Fortran function in Mathematica. I was following mainly this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5455/how-can-i-deploy-dll-files-created-by-a-fortran-function-and-call-them-from-math) . My Fortran code looks like this:

```
FUNCTION TESTFUNCTION(X,Y)

!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::TESTFUNCTION
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: X,Y

REAL(8), DIMENSION(2) :: X
REAL(8) :: Y, TESTFUNCTION
TESTFUNCTION = (X(1)+X(2)) * Y

END FUNCTION
```

To create
    .dll
I have used Intel Fortran Compiler, while following this [guide](https://sukhbinder.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/how-to-create-fortran-dll-in-visual-studio-with-intel-fortran-compiler/) . My Mathematica input is:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
ReinstallNET["Force32Bit" -> True]
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
path = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "testfunction.dll"}];

TestFunction = DefineDLLFunction["TESTFUNCTION_",path ,
"double", {"double[]", "double*"}]
```

This gives:

```
(*
Out[26]=Function[Null, 
If[NETLink`DLL`Private`checkArgCount["TESTFUNCTION_", {##1}, 2], 
Wolfram`NETLink`DynamicDLLNamespace`DLLWrapper1`TESTFUNCTIONU[##1], \
$Failed], {HoldAll}]
*)
```

After calling

```
TestFunction[{1.0, 2.0}, 3.0]
```

I've obtained

```
(*
 Out[27]= NET::netexcptn: 
 A .NET exception occurred: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 
 Unable to find an entry point named 'TESTFUNCTION_'   
 in DLL 'D:\Files\testfunction\testfunction.dll'.
 at Wolfram.NETLink.DynamicDLLNamespace.DLLWrapper1.TESTFUNCTION_(Double[] ,Double& ).
*)
```

Can somebody please tell why I have this error message. Any suggestions are more than welcomed. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x3vtfltw2dv7t1m/AABcrjksPecUVxts6IcrEmLaa?dl=0) is the source code and .dll file.

Comment: try without the `_`

Comment: @george2079 I've tried that, but with any success (same error message)

Comment: Have you solved it? I have encountered the same problem.

Comment: @xinpei try to run it with updated files which I have just uploaded on my dropbox. I think that with these new files it is working. It is been 2 years, so I am not sure :) Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks @Moonwalk it don't work on my computer. But i found if i use Gfortran this error will not occur.