# How to integrate a function written in fortran that solves a set of nonlinear equations into mathematica?

Tags: .netlink, fortran

I am trying to integrate the solver for the set of nonlinear equations [link](https://github.com/yoki/Optimization/) written in Fortran language into mathematica . To do so i developed a function called netlib based on the explanation given in [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5455/how-can-i-deploy-dll-files-created-by-a-fortran-function-and-call-them-from-math/5637#5637)

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
GFortran1[name_, inp_] := (
  Export[name <> ".f90", inp, "Text"];
  string1 = "!gfortran -c " <> name <> ".f90 ";
  string2 = 
   "!gfortran -s -shared -mrtd -o " <> name <> ".dll " <> name <> ".o";
  Column@ReadList[string1, String];
  Column@ReadList[string2, String])
netlink[name_, code_, fun_] := Block[{string1, string2},

  ReinstallNET["Force32Bit" -> True];
  ReinstallNET["Force32Bit" -> False];
  SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
  path = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], name <> ".dll"}];
  If[fun == 1,
   (Evaluate@ToExpression@name) = 
    DefineDLLFunction[name <> "_", path, 
     "double", {"double[]", "double*"}], (Evaluate@
      ToExpression@name) = 
    DefineDLLFunction[name <> "_", path, 
     "void", {"Double[]", "Double*", "Double[]"}]];
  DeleteFile[{name <> ".f90", name <> ".dll", name <> ".o", 
    name <> ".mod"}];
  GFortran1[name, code];
  ]
```

and it works like this

[image]

[image]

So now with a slight modification of the FsolveHybridTest subroutine (x0 is the initial condition and xout2 is the result) in the hybrid.f90 file (to save the results in a file called results.txt) and  debug_hybrid.f90

[image]
[image]

it is possible to call the netlink function to get the correct result (replace ... with a correct directory)

```
name = {"myutility", "hybrid", "debug_hybrid"};
Table[
  pr = Import[
    ".../Optimization-master/" <> name[[ix]] <> 
     ".f90", {"Text"}];
  Quiet@netlink[name[[ix]], pr, 2], {ix, Length@name}];
Run["gfortran myutility.o hybrid.f90  debug_hybrid.o -o resx.exe"];
Run["resx.exe"]
result = ReadList["...\\results.txt", Real]
```

[image]

So now my question is that how can we modify the debug_hybrid.f90 (main program that calls fsolvehybrid) file to act as a subroutine that gets the initial values and returns the result?

Comment: how can we convert mathematica file to fortran file?

Comment: I understand this is not your question but have you tried `FindRoot` for you root finding?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM the other way around

Comment: @user21 yes but i was wondering if this code can perform faster since it has some fancy jacobian update.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationAffineCovariantNewton.html)?

Comment: @user21 I have not seen that before. thanks for providing me the link. It looks very interesting. I must also add, although i have asked a specific question, other people might want to integrate other functions to mathematica or even write theirs

Comment: @user49047  which routine or program is possible?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  what do you mean ?

Comment: @user49047 The way which converts mathematica file to fortran file.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM still not clear what you are asking me but the debug_hybrid.f90 file contains a program(shown in the figure)  that calls FsolveHybridTest subroutine(uses hybrid module). the FsolveHybridTest subroutine has the initial value itself. my question is that how to change this program so that it gets an initial value and pass it to FsolveHybridTest subroutine.