# Passing vectors into a Fortran function and getting out a vector

Tags: fortran

I am writing a Fortran function that needs to receive two vectors of reals, and as an output, returns a vector. The function could be for example the sum of the two vectors:

```
function sumtwovectors( n, v1, v2 )

implicit none
real(kind=8), dimension(100000)             :: sumtwovectors
integer, intent(in)                         :: n
real(kind=8), dimension(100000), intent(in) :: v1, v2

integer :: i

if (n .gt. 100000) then
    sumtwovectors(:) = -99
    return
endif

do i = 1, n
    sumtwovectors(i) = v1(i) + v2(i)
enddo

return

end function sumtwovectors
```

which is then compiled without error into a dll with

```
gfortran -c sumtwovectors.f90 -o sumtwovectors.o
gfortran -shared -mrtd -o test.dll sumtwovectors.o
```

This dll should be NET-compatible, so I load it into Mathematica ( `path` contains the path where the dll is stored):

```
InstallNET[];
sumtwovectors = DefineDLLFunction["sumtovectors_", path, "double[]", {"short*", "double[]", "double[]"}]
```

but when I run this, I have an error:

```
sumtwovectors[3, {1, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 5}]

NET::netexcptn: A .NET exception occurred: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: Impossible de marshaler 'return value' : Combinaison de types managés/non managés non valide.
à Wolfram.NETLink.DynamicDLLNamespace.DLLWrapper1.sumtovectors_(Int16& , Double[] , Double[] ).
```

1. How can I make this work in Mathematica? I tried enclosing the two list into MakeNETObject[] but to no avail.
2. Instead of having a maximum size (1000000), could it work with no defined maximum size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment from I.M. "*C functions do not return arrays*" made me try a different approach with a subroutine rather than a function.

Let the Fortran subroutine be

```
subroutine vsum( n, v1, v2, v3 )

implicit none
integer, intent(in)                          :: n
real(kind=8), dimension(100000), intent(in)  :: v1, v2
real(kind=8), dimension(100000), intent(out) :: v3

integer :: i

do i = 1, n
    v3(i) = v1(i) + v2(i)
enddo

return

end subroutine vsum
```

in which v3 is an ouptut argument that will be used to return the answer.  This file is compiled to a dynamically-link library (DLL) with

```
gfortran -c vsum.f90 -o vsum.o
gfortran -shared - mrtd -o vsum.dll vsum.o
```

In Mathematica, load and install the NETLink library, define the function, and initialize a container `NETres` that will receive the result:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];
sumtwovectors = 
  DefineDLLFunction["vsum_", path <> "vsum.dll", 
   "void", {"short*", "double[]", "double[]", "double[]"}
];
NETres = MakeNETObject[{0., 0., 0.}];
```

You are ready to use the function and unpack the `NETres` container:

```
sumtwovectors[3, {N[Pi], 10., 1000.}, {100., 100., 100.}, NETres]
NETObjectToExpression[NETres]
```

Comment: This approach was also mentioned 8 years ago [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5637/29), though I am not so sure how well supported and robust `NETLink` is (on Windows, but also on Linux and MacOSX, as  Mono).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with .NET interface for WM, but your problem can be solved with [LibraryLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LibraryLink.html). With LibraryLink it is possible to create a shared lib which can be loaded with `LibraryFunctionLoad[]` or, perhaps, this lib can be accessed with .NET interface.

`Fortran` has interoperability with `C`. While it is possible to call `Fortran` functions with `<name>_`, the modern way is to use the intrinsic `iso_c_binding` module.

You want to interface a function that returns an array. It's OK in `Fortran`, but `C` functions do not return arrays. A solution is to use a `subroutine` in `Fortran` and a `void` function in `C`.

Create `funs.f90`, `test.c`, `test.f90` and `interface.cpp` in your notebook directory (see files contents below or download all files [forum.tar.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EWUv0WNHQ5Zehabkoqk3s3dluAYzs1zH/view?usp=sharing))

```
(* set directory *)
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]] ;
```

You can define your `Fortran` procedures in a module.

```
(* fortran module *)
FilePrint["funs.f90"]
```

```
module funs
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : ik => c_int, rk => c_double
  implicit none
  private
  public :: ik
  public :: rk
  public :: vsum
  contains
  ! void vsum(int, double*, double*, double*) ;
  pure subroutine vsum(n, v1, v2, v3) bind(c, name = "vsum")
    integer(ik), value, intent(in) :: n
    real(rk), dimension(n), intent(in) :: v1
    real(rk), dimension(n), intent(in) :: v2
    real(rk), dimension(n), intent(out) :: v3
    v3 = v1 + v2
  end subroutine vsum
end module funs
```

Note, array dims are set by the input arg `n`. Array length `n` also has `value` keyword which allows to pass it by value in `C`.

```
(* compile fortran module *)
Run["gfortran -c -std=f2008 -O3 funs.f90"]
(* 0 *)
```

Here is a test `Fortran` program that uses this module.

```
(* fortran test program *)
FilePrint["test.f90"]
```

```
program test
  use funs
  implicit none
  integer(ik), parameter :: n = 16_ik
  real(rk), dimension(n) :: v1, v2, v3
  integer(ik) :: i
  v1 = real([(i, i = 1_ik, n, 1_ik)], rk)
  v2 = v1
  call vsum(n, v1, v2, v3)
  do i = 1_ik, n, 1_ik
    write(*,*) v3(i)
  end do
end program test
```

```
(* compile and run fortran test program *)
Run["gfortran -c -std=f2008 -O3 test.f90"]
Run["gfortran -o test -std=f2008 -O3 funs.o test.o"]
ImportString[RunProcess["./test", "StandardOutput"],"List"]
(*0*)
(*0*)
(*{2.,4.,6.,8.,10.,12.,14.,16.,18.,20.,22.,24.,26.,28.,30.,32.}*)
```

Here is a test `C` program that uses this module.

```
(* c test program *)
FilePrint["test.c"]
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
void vsum(int, double*, double*, double*) ;
int main(){
  int n = 16 ;
  double x[n], y[n], z[n] ;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    x[i] = (double) i + 1 ;
    y[i] = (double) i + 1;
    z[i] = 0.0 ;
  }
  vsum(n, x, y, z) ;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    printf("%lf\n",z[i]) ;
  }
  return 0 ;
}
```

```
(* compile and run c test program *)
Run["gcc -c -std=c99 -O3 test.c"]
Run["gcc -o test -std=c99 -O3 funs.o test.o"]
ImportString[RunProcess["./test", "StandardOutput"],"List"]
(*0*)
(*0*)
(*{2.,4.,6.,8.,10.,12.,14.,16.,18.,20.,22.,24.,26.,28.,30.,32.}*)
```

For `LibraryLink` you need to define a wrapper.

```
(* library link *)
FilePrint["interface.cpp"]
```

```
#include "WolframLibrary.h"
#include "WolframCompileLibrary.h"
DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion(){ return WolframLibraryVersion ; }
DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData){ return 0 ; }
extern "C" { void vsum(int, double*, double*, double*) ;}
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int vsum_ll(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){
  mint n = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]) ;
  MTensor v1 = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[1]) ;
  MTensor v2 = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[2]) ;
  MTensor v3 = 0 ;
  libData->MTensor_clone(v1, &v3);
  vsum(
    n,
    MTensor_getRealDataMacro(v1),
    MTensor_getRealDataMacro(v2),
    MTensor_getRealDataMacro(v3)
  ) ;
  MArgument_setMTensor(Res,v3) ;
  return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR ;
}
```

```
(* create library *)
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"] ;
CreateLibrary[
    {"interface.cpp", "funs.o"},
    "vsum_ll",
    "TargetDirectory" -> NotebookDirectory[],
    "CleanIntermediate" -> True,
    "Debug" -> False,
    "CompileOptions" -> "-O3"
] ;
```

This creates `vsum_ll` lib with `vsum_ll` function that calls `vsum` procedure.
You can try to load it with .NET or with `LibraryFunctionLoad[]`.

```
(* load library *)
Quiet[LibraryFunctionUnload[lib]] ;
ClearAll[lib] ;
lib = LibraryFunctionLoad[
    FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"vsum_ll"}],
    "vsum_ll",
    {Integer,{Real,1},{Real,1}},
    {Real,1}
] ;
```

This function can now be used in WM.

```
(* test *)
n = 16 ;
v1 = v2 = N[Range[n]] ;
lib[n,v1,v2]
(*{2.,4.,6.,8.,10.,12.,14.,16.,18.,20.,22.,24.,26.,28.,30.,32.}*)
```

As an extra step, you can wrap it into `Compile[]`, this allows to use listability and also provides some safety.

```
(* wrapper *)
ClearAll[vsum] ;
vsum = Compile[
    {{n,_Integer},{v1,_Real,1},{v2,_Real,1}},
    lib[n,v1,v2],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True},
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
] ;
```

Test wrapped version and instability.

```
(* test *)
(* sequential *)
vsum[n,v1,v2]
(* listable *)
vsum[n,{v1,v1},{v2,v2}]
(*{2.,4.,6.,8.,10.,12.,14.,16.,18.,20.,22.,24.,26.,28.,30.,32.}*)
(*{{2.,4.,6.,8.,10.,12.,14.,16.,18.,20.,22.,24.,26.,28.,30.,32.},{2.,4.,6.,8.,10.,12.,14.,16.,18.,20.,22.,24.,26.,28.,30.,32.}}*)
```

Unload lib when done.

```
(* unload *)
LibraryFunctionUnload[lib]
```

You can find more examples of Fortran in WM [here](https://github.com/i-a-morozov/SIGNAL) or [here](https://github.com/i-a-morozov/PROPAGANDA).

Comment: Thank you very much for you very complete answer. It was very helpful. However, the complexity of the process (using a C wrapper to a fortran function) is precisely something I wanted to avoid.

Comment: "... but C functions do not return arrays" Ahah, I didn't know about this. Modifying the fortran code to have two input vectors and one ouptut vectors should make things easier?

Comment: @DenisCousineau, yes, `Fortran` code is changed (function is replaced by subroutine) to match void `C` function. The wrapper is for `Cpp` which is used in `LibraryLink`, it uses an external `C` function which in fact is a `Fortran` sub. Basically, you just need to interface an external `C` in `C#`.

Comment: @DenisCousineau, if you insist on using `function` in `Fortran`, you can wrap it in `subroutine` and then use it in `C`. Perhaps, this can be done with pointers, but I do not have such experience.